# How to use an external camera when using the CameraX API

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am using CameraX api in Android and need the analyse function to analyse he image from the camera. But I need to use an external camera connected via wifi/bluetooth.

How do i build the

```
CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CameraFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraFilter) API. Example:

```
CameraSelector.Builder().addCameraFilter { cameraInfos ->
  cameraInfos.filter {
    cameraId.value == externalCameraId
  }
}.build()
```